# Spacy v3 - reading DocBin to a json or pandas

Tags: python, spacy

Is it possible to be able to read `.spacy` file as a regular format - e.g. pandas or dict so that we may use it in e.g. sklearn?

Suppose we have a spacy DocBin object:

```
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc_bin = DocBin()

df= pd.read_json("../data/data.jsonl", lines = True)
df.head()

doc_bin = DocBin()

for text, label in zip(df['text'], df['label']):
    doc = nlp(text)
    doc.cats[label] = True
    doc_bin.add(doc)

doc_bin.to_disk('train.spacy')
```

How would we read `train.spacy` into dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to read a `.spacy` file directy into a dict or something in a meaningful way. It's a serialization format specifically for spaCy Doc objects.

You can always read the Docs in and convert them to whatever you want to put in a dict afterwards.